# Print origin Typescript Function Definition

Tags: typescript

As I understand, Javascript Function prototype has a method to print its own definition: `toString()` like below:

```js
function example() {
  // do something here
}

console.log(example.toString());
```

I tried to use the function in Typescript, got the compiled function definition in Javascript. However, the thing I want is the origin Typescript function definition, what I had written.

Is there any way for me to get what I expect?
Or is it able to implement a new feature like that for Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only and long way is to use TypeScript compiler api, you have to create your own separate node package which will contain your own typescript compiler which internally will use TypeScript compiler.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API

In this, they have given some examples, I think it should be fairly easy if you know how to rewrite AST and generate an additional `.toString` for every function that can return a constant string having typescript function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have created a simple compiler to compile the code as I expect.